# Flash game engine

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need simple game engine with pixel-perfect collision detection, camera component with following function, network and particle components would be desirable.
Anyone knows whether the engine right under these requirements?

Comment: I suspect you'll get more traction on this sort of question over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend either [Flixel](http://flixel.org/) or [Flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net/). The [Flash Game Dojo](http://flashgamedojo.com/go/) is a great place to find out about both of these libraries...

Comment: maybe you tell how to make PPCollision with flixel or flashpunk?

Comment: http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/66889.aspx Hmm, it looks really easy in Flashpunk... All you have to do is specify mask data, and it all works fine. I guess Flixel is good too, but I haven't looked very hard yet.

Answer (score 4):

[FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.org) is able to do exactly what you want. Furthermore, the [FlashPunk Community](http://flashpunk.net/forums/) is lovely awesome and really helpful.

Pixelmask is easily implementable in FlashPunk, all you have to do is pass a BitmapData to the `mask` property of an `Entity` and the rest will be handled for you. More information in the docs: [net.flashpunk.masks.Pixelmask](http://flashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/masks/Pixelmask.html).

For camera, following would be translated as this in your entity:

```
override public function update():void
{
    super.update();
    FP.camera.x = x;
    FP.camera.y = y;
}
```

And if you want easing and that stuff, you can use FlashPunk `Tweens` or take a look at the view class from the [Advanced Platform Engine](http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?topic=738.0).

Particle Emitters are supported by default as well. Here you have a [comprehensive tutorial about FlashPunk Emitters](http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?topic=1310.0).

About Network… I'm sad that there's no included network system on FlashPunk. Luckily, there are a lot of Network systems for AS3 which you can adapt very easily for FlashPunk. [SmartFoxServer](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/2X/) and [Player.IO](http://playerio.com/) are good examples of AS3 Network systems.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/flash-game-engine) question on gamedev stackexchange. Unfortunately it only got 2 answers.

However, there's:
[Flixel](http://flixel.org/)
[Pushbutton](http://pushbuttonengine.com/)
[Flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net/)

[A comparison of Flixel and Flashpunk.](http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=576.0;wap2)